# Can't choose Contact as Entry Source in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am having an issue with Journey Builder Entry Source. I want to use my synchronized Sales Cloud data as the entry source.
When I choose Lead as my Entry Source - no problem, the lead is there and I can choose Lead ID (Lead):

[image]

But when I want to do the same for Contact, the Contact ID (Contact) is not there:

[image]

The data model was inherited from Sales Cloud and looks fine.
Any idea why I can't choose a Contact for my entry source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears on first glance that you have PersonAccounts configured in your Sales Cloud. If you want to send to those you have to select Account and use PersoncontactId.

If you also still use Business Accounts and want to send to their Contacts you should still use PersoncontactId, if I remember correctly.