# With Person Account activated, what Salesforce ID as Subscriber Key/Contact Key in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, person-accounts, marketing-cloud-connect, subscriber-key

When person account are activated on a Salesforce org connected to SFMC with MC Connect, what are the best practices regarding the Subscriber key and Contact key ?
Should we use the (person) account ID or the contact ID as Subscriber key AND Contact key in SFMC? (Especially, when creating a Sendable Data Extension, we have to define the Send Relationship.)
Or does SFMC automatically use one of these ID as subscriber key AND contact key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Orgs with PersonAccounts enabled, you still will be using PersonContactID as Subscriber Key. There is more info on Subscriber Keys in a multi cloud scenario in [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_subscriber_key.htm&type=5).

It can be difficult to find the Contact ID in a setup where PersonAccounts are enabled, as the contact redirects to the Account page. For this purpose I use the [Salesforce Inspector Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh), which is able to display all the fields on a PersonAccount page, including Contact ID.

Comment: I sort of answered this here in a slightly different context (it's PersoncontactId): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/263008/31594

Comment: I second the notion, it makes a lot of sense to show the PersonContactId on the Account layout, otherwise it will be very confusing. 
As an alternative to the chrome extension, I typically use a formula field on the account with the following formula: 

CASESAFEID (PersonContact.Id)

Comment: Hello Stephan, in the case you mention in the link it is said : "It appears on first glance that you have PersonAccounts configured in your Sales Cloud. If you want to send to those you have to select Account and use PersoncontactId." Is the PersonContactId the same ID as the ContactID ? If not, how should we manage the SubscriberKey and ContactKey with different kinds of ID ? Thank you

Comment: PersonContactId is indeed the same as ContactId - you can verify this when you look at the first three characters in the ID. ContactId always begins with 003

Comment: Also, @LudivineL - remember to mark the answer as accepted, if it has been helpful